# vsftpd will not start with SSL enabled

Tags: 13.10, ftp, vsftpd, openssl

I am having a problem trying to set up an FTPS server on my Ubuntu Server 13.10 machine. I have vsftpd installed.

When I try to start the service using `sudo service vsftpd start` I get :

`vsftpd start/pre-start, process 5922`

However, `ps aux | grep vsftpd` yields nothing.

I found this error in `/var/log/dmesg`:

`[   11.212518] init: vsftpd main process (1137) terminated with status 2`

The result of `sudo vsftpd` is:

`500 OOPS: SSL: cannot load RSA certificate`

The permissions on `\etc\vsftpd\vsftpd.pem` are currently set to:

`-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1708 Jan 28 05:15 vsftpd.pem`

I tried changing the permissions to 777 and it still didn't work.

I used the following command to create the certificate:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 720 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem`

My `/etc/vsftpd.conf` is as follows:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
listen_port=2000
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
hide_ids=YES
max_per_ip=10
max_clients=10
port_enable=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=11000
pasv_max_port=11030
require_ssl_reuse=NO
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am officially drawing a total blank.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I just tried it with:

```
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

It worked. So I'm thinking that I messed up the certificate generation. I don't really know enough about OpenSSL to figure it out any further.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out. I changed the openssl generation command from:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 720 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem`

to:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 720 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.key -out /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem`

Resulting in a `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem` and a `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.key`.

I updated `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and the service started right up.